# React-Native-Image-Picker : null is no an object (evaluating) error

Tags: react-native

When I use the react-native-image-picker(^3.11.1), for getting image from gallery there is error occurs something like below.

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.ImagePickerManager.launchImageLibrary')

```
const onPresslaunchGallery = () => {
const options = {mediaType: 'photo'};
launchImageLibrary(options, (resp) => {
  if (resp.fileName && resp.uri) {
    setAvatar(resp);
  }
  console.log('resp', resp);
});
```

};

Using expo and after expo install react-native-image-picker but the error is still appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen the full source code of yours, but here is the working example showing how you can get images from a gallery and show them.

**Here is the full working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/eager-hummus)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Image, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function Add() {
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState(null);

  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission

    const imagePermission = await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(imagePermission.status);

    setGalleryPermission(imagePermission.status === 'granted');

    if (imagePermission.status !== 'granted') {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  const pick = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImageUri(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {imageUri ? (
        <Image
          source={{ uri: imageUri }}
          style={{ flex: 1, borderRadius: 10, margin: 5 }}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.textBox}>
          <Text>No Image Selected</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      <Button title={'Pick From Gallery'} onPress={pick} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  textBox: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: nice one but what if filename is required? As there is no filename in result when using expo image picker